# Validation Messages not showing on login page

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a controller called Account Controller which houses my login function. The problem I am having its going straight to the index page instead of displaying the Model Error for invalid login.

In aps.net web forms their used to be a validation group and a validationsummary is the same required here

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login");
            return View();
        }
        if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Confirm your email first");
            return View();
        }

        var passwordSignInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent: rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);



        if (!passwordSignInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login");
            return View();
        }

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

Login Page

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true"> Remember Me
                    <input type="hidden" name="rememberMe" value="false" />

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    </form>
```

My Startup.cs Configure in case anything is missing.

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried your code and it works fine and shows Index page only when no errors were added to ModelState.

Validationsummary is still present in ASP.NET Core you can use it like below.

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">

    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    ...
    </form>
```

When I used this code, errors displayed on page without any issues.
[image]

But as suggestion you can improve your code a bit and instead of many `return View();` in code just use this code in the end of the method before `return Redirect("~/")`

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();
```

**UPDATE**: There is the full code of Login method.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login");
        return View();//this should be kept because if user NULL, PasswordSignInAsync will generate exception
    }
    if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Confirm your email first");
    }

    var passwordSignInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent: rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (!passwordSignInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

**UPDATE2**: 
The easiest way, in my opinion, to handle empty emails in this case is just using **required** attribute in your View for email field like below.

```
<input required type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

This **required** attribute specifies that the user must fill in a value before submitting a form, without entering value for email you will not be able to submit form, therefore you will not get exception. You can read more about required attribute [here](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-required.php) and plus another [link about form validation(see required attribute section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: thats weird it dont allow me to get rid of the other returns says doesnt return all codes paths can you show the function how it should be Could u also show the full login you used did you have a model at the top ? I am using a layout file for that page should that make a diff

Comment: that is returning a blank view to me not even showing the login view now.

Comment: that works great but what happens when email is null I get an expcetion how do i handle that

Comment: @david. Glad to help. About empty email issue check UPDATE2 section in my answer.

Comment: is there a way more to get a more useful message like there just as invalid login nothing to say if email was invalid or if ti was the password. also with identity how does one add first name and last name in core its changes so much hard to keep up with.

Comment: @Just change the "Invalid login" in ModelState.AddModelError to something more meaningful like "You specified wrong email" or "Wrong password". That's it.

Comment: About 1st/last name more complicated you can see how it is done in this article https://medium.com/@goodealsnow/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4.